# OAuth2 without forwarding to an external site

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a React-Native project with my own backend

I have to use OAuth2, but I want to have the user enter their name and password and not forward them to Facebook / Google, for example

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only grant types that allow acquiring tokens without redirects are the `client_credentials` and the `password` (resource owner password grant). Both of them are only feasible if you are running your own Identity Server (like Keycloak).

For identity federation with external systems, you will always need a flow that redirects the end user (at the very least in an iframe). The user authenticates against *Google*, not against *your system*. Google then issues a Token, and *your application* can verify the token was issued by Google. A system without a redirect would be equal to each and every user giving you their Google password.

This is the kind of thing that OAuth2 was designed to prevent, and so it is not possible.